# PHP strpos($a, $b) >= 0 is true even when $b is not in $a

Tags: php

After reading [How do I check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/php-how-to-check-if-a-string-contain-specific-words) and the documentation about `strpos()` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php, I try an alternative of the first link, instead of `!==`, I use `>= 0`

```
$a = "Hello";
$b = "a";
if(strpos($a, $b) >= 0) {
  echo 'string found';
} else {
  echo 'string not found';
}
```

prints `'string found'` and not `'string not found'`? `$b` is obviously not in `$a`, so `strpos()` should return `false`, hence it should enter the `else`, what's going on here?

Comment: `>=` 0 is not an alternative of `!==`. It is in this context close to `!=`, which is totally different from `!==`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - How to check if a string contain specific words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/php-how-to-check-if-a-string-contain-specific-words)

Answer (score 2):

In that case, strpos did return false. However, any value other than 0 is treated as true in php, including negatives that is, **and** 0 is treated as false. So,

```
if(strpos($a, $b) >= 0)
```

is evaluated into

```
if(false >= 0)
```

and then

```
if(0 >= 0)
```

which is true

You should use `!== false` instead, so `if(strpos($a, $b) !== false)`

Comment: There is no `>==` operator in PHP. Read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I did http://codepad.org/AjUOVKuX and it did: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 2

Comment: Replaced by `!== false` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the manual: php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

You will notice that strpos will return false is $b is not in $a. You will need to check it this way:

```
<?php
$a = "Hello";
$b = "a";
if(strpos($a, $b) !== false) {
  echo 'string found';
} else {
  echo 'string not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($a, $b) >= 0) 
strpos($a, $b) returns false
if(false >= 0) is true.
```

Here we need to check type.